# Non color diff for review

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, diff

When reviewing Suggested Edits the output is marked using red and green background colors on the text. Sometimes this makes it hard to see the actual changes.

It would be nice if there was a button that turns off the diff color highlighting as long as the mouse is pressed on it (or hovers it or whatever), so one can switch fast between the "natural" look and the diff view.

**Just to avoid misunderstandings:** The color diff should stay the default view as it does a great job in helping to locate the changes, but it does not help in evaluating them.

Comment: That would be nice, and I think colorblind people would agree with you

Answer (score 8):

I would like to add something to this feature request. I came across a suggested edit that changed quite a lot source code formatting and indenting. As [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169611/improved-way-of-reviewing-improved-formatting) states, this
*"is a blur of overstrikes, red and green in a text that is **half the width** that it usually is"* (emphasis by me).

In addition to the feature request made by the asker (addressing the "red-and-green-in-text-issue), I would like to suggest that when the button <kbd>Show Final</kbd> is being pressed the post is not only displayed without any difference indicators, but also in **full width**.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond just a toggle, I'd like a simple scroll bar to fade the highlighting up and down. As it currently stands I think it's about 3 times too strong. I'd like to still see it, but not as bright. Especially for small characters like back ticks, it gets too hard to read the actual text.