# Improved way of reviewing "improved formatting"

Tags: feature-request, review, diff

When I review posts, I often see "improved formatting" but when looking down on the post in the narrow side by side view, with rendered output, all I can focus on is a blur of overstrikes, red and green in a text that is half the width that it usually is. This sometimes makes it hard to see if anything is improved at all.

What I would like was to have either have the possibility to turn off/on the diff colour output, and the opportunity to turn of the side by side and view only the original and only the edit. This would allow for a quicker resolution for all reviews that is based on the look of the question/answer. I am not suggesting to remove the colors or the side by side view, they are fantastic tools for reviewing, only an option to turn them off.

I understand that the text is viewed in many different widths and should look as good as possible at any width. But dividing the review and the edit would make them narrower than most people view it anyway.

I know that I could look at the complete answer/question at the original question site, but this will require me to load a new tab and it doesn't let me view how the edited answer would look in the original context.

If any of these features already exists, there is either a problem with me being an unnaturally inattentive user or a problem with the UI.

Comment: Couldn't you switch to "side-by-side" there? (I don't see any Suggested Edits on my site in 10k tools, so I can't verify it now.)

Comment: Side by side is part of the problem. It narrows the view so much text wraps around. This makes fixes in indentation very hard to judge.

Answer (score 2):

> ... and the opportunity to view only the original and only the edit.

You can already see this. The left side is the original post and the edit is on the right. If you ignore the red/green strikes, you can see how it looked and how it looks now.

The red/green text shows you what is deleted and what was added.

I recommend you to switch to the `markdown` view instead of the `rendered output` if you have edits like 'improved formatting'. If the formatting is improved, you can see what exactly has changed in the formatting in the `markdown` view.

> But dividing the review and the edit would make them narrower than most people view it anyway.

I don't think this is a problem. What can change on wider screens?

Comment: I want to see the original by itself, the edit. That is to change the width to more normal format. What changes with width is the readability of the text. It is next to impossible to see if the indentation makes more sense when lines wrap around. Also the red green text also distorts the view of formatting. I usually use both markdown and rendered. But "improve formatting" is more about the overview. I believe that when looking at a original post in almost original context, and then the edit in the same context makes it easier to judge the overview.