# Actual Display Comparison Feature for Edit Review

Tags: feature-request

I have had a few rejects of edits which improved formatting of code blocks on the basis that the improvement was minor.

Looking at the representation of the edit in both 'rendered output' and 'markdown', it is difficult to visualize the actual formatting improvement as it would display in the question or answer.

I suspect that other formatting improvements may also be difficult to visualize, and are not supported by the render output (like color coding of code). Other posts have suggested that the diff markup in certain instances makes it difficult to visualize the changes.

Would it not be beneficial to add an additional view 'actual display' rendering the before and after as it would display?

That way if it is not immediately apparent to the reviewer the benefit of the edit, they can check the actual display to make sure that there indeed is no benefit.

Comment: How is `rendered output` different from `actual display`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The *rendered output* still shows a diff.

Comment: Then the question could do with making that explicit.

Comment: From what I can gather, this would be to create a new view (alongside "rendered output" and "markdown") that would be identical to "rendered output", but without showing differences?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non color diff for review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151960/non-color-diff-for-review)

Comment: Now that I go back and look at my edits (which were strictly indentation formatting to make aspx markup legible), the difference is it does not render with color coding, and the changes in indentation are marked with a different background color. The improvement is more obvious in the actual display rendered on the question page.

Comment: @Spontifixus I am suggesting an option to display the original and edited question/answer side by side, as they would display on the actual question page, which I am not sure the post you refer to is suggesting

Comment: ...which is exactly what a "non color diff" would result in.

Comment: this may be a duplicate, although the OP of the other feature request does not explicitly request a display of 'as is'. You even go on to clarify that it should be full width in your answer. The most straight forward expression of the feature is **provide a view that exactly replicates the before and after question/answer as it would appear the stack x site.**